# Imacros Drop Down Menu

Tags: drop-down-menu, imacros

I am using the firefox addon of imacros. From this link: http://www.youtube.com/create_account I am trying to click the month drop down menu and select a month (for example June). When I record no code shows up, so I tried writing it myself but I am stuck. I know I can right click and select inspect element and look through the markup but I don't see the names for this button.

**EDIT** - Now offering a $5 reward through paypal to the answer that shows how to click and select a month through iMacros.

Comment: Have you tried putting $ sign before the value, e.g CONTENT=$June.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to just use java to scan the screen for the drop down menu and do what I want whenever it appears.