# iMacros for Firefox won't record selection in drop down menu

Tags: drop-down-menu, imacros

I am trying record selecting a value from a dropdown menu in iMacros for Firefox/Mac. This is what I do:
https://youtu.be/xweQ7XOPbfo

This results in the following macro (the three first lines, which are not of interest, are omitted):

```
URL GOTO=http://skicka2.posten.se/Sidor/Start.aspx
TAG POS=5 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:aspnetForm ATTR=* CONTENT=49
```

The selection in the drowdown named "Välj tjänst" ("select service") should go
between line one and two above, but nothing is recorded, and thus running the macro is pointless.

This appears to be similar to this problem:
[Imacros Drop Down Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993369/imacros-drop-down-menu)
However, that problem did not get any relevant answer (the one person answering it seems to have misunderstood the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be simple. You even have two ways to select a certain value from the dropdown. For example:

```
TAG POS=2 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ID:aspnetForm ATTR=* CONTENT=$PostNord<SP>Parcel
```

or this:

```
TAG POS=2 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ID:aspnetForm ATTR=* CONTENT=#7
```

etc.

Comment: The weird this is that it works the first time I run it, but the second time I get this error message: 'RuntimeError: Entry with index 8 not available [Box has 1 entries], line: 3'

Comment: I noticed that the number of entries depends on the first 'Land' dropdown box item, so try to use the first approach, i.e. `TAG POS=2 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ID:aspnetForm ATTR=* CONTENT=$PostNord<SP>Parcel` and so on.

Comment: So I try this and code now looks like this: 
`VERSION BUILD=844 RECORDER=CR
URL GOTO=http://skicka2.posten.se/Sidor/Start.aspx
TAG POS=2 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ID:aspnetForm ATTR=* CONTENT=$Rek
TAG POS=3 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ID:aspnetForm ATTR=* CONTENT=$Brev<SP>C4
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:BUTTON FORM=ID:aspnetForm ATTR=ID:ctl00_m_g_da7f524c_9ea6_4aa0_b301_5be99d07afb8_ctl00_displayControl_showProposalsButton
`  
However, this only gets me to line 3. On line 4 I get this error message: 
`RuntimeError: element SELECT specified by * was not found, line: 4`  
  
Any clues?

Comment: I don't see any problems at all. Try the following macro: `URL GOTO=http://skicka2.posten.se/Sidor/Start.aspx
TAG POS=2 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ID:aspnetForm ATTR=* CONTENT=$Rek
WAIT SECONDS=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:RADIO FORM=ID:aspnetForm ATTR=NAME:standard
WAIT SECONDS=1` etc.